# External bus interfacing

Tags: microcontroller, memory, microprocessor, computer-architecture, sram

This lab requires us to extend the memory and I/O ports on our µPad using our EBI backpack. What I'm confused about is how the fully address decoded SRAM will differ from the partially addressed i/o ports. And will the i/o ports have the same address range? Please help with parts a and b!
[image: #]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you! I completely agree, I really didn't want the answer, just a clarification. I agree that giving the answer is a disservice. I should have put my current work already, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm confused about is how the fully address decoded SRAM will differ from the partially addressed i/o ports.

"Partial decoding" simply means that even though each port only requires 1 byte,
it occupies 64 bytes worth of address space.

In other words, no matter which of the 64 possible addresses you use, you're accessing the same hardware port.

On the other hand, the SRAM occupies one block of addresses, and each address within that block accesses a unique location within the SRAM.

> And will the i/o ports have the same address range?

Yes.

Comment: I have determined that the CS0 (first chip select) = (/A23*/A22*A21*A20*/A19*A18*A17*A16) which will be used for the SRAM (that begins at address 0x37 0000). However, I am not confident with the addressing for the I/O ports. Given that the addressing for this begins at 0x19000 and requires only 64 addresses, is it safe to assume that the end address will be 0x01903F? I am not confident in suggesting that the CS will be equal to (/A23.../A21*A20*A19*/A18*/A17*A16) when some are meant to be "don't cares"..